# How does the std::unique_ptr&& function argument work?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, unique-ptr, ownership

I'm writing a simple game engine in C++.

I'm very late to C++, because I've spent most of my free time with C, so the `unique_ptr`, `shared_ptr` and all of this ownership magic is hardly understandable for me.

I stumbled upon one thing that I can't understand at all. Let's have a following snippet:

```cpp
#include <memory>
#include "vertexArray.hpp" // here VertexArray class is defined, it's implementation isn't important I think

class Mesh {
public:
    Mesh()= default;
    Mesh(std::unique_ptr<VertexArray>&& vertexArray) {
        // this->vertexArray = vertexArray; <- this doesn't work
        this->vertexArray = std::move(vertexArray); // Why is the move necessary?
    }
private:
    std::unique_ptr<VertexArray> vertexArray;
};

int main() {
    auto vArray = std::make_unique<VertexArray>(/* vertex buffer, index buffer, etc */);
    Mesh mesh = Mesh(std::move(vArray)); // <- I have to move the unique_ptr here, that I understand
}
```

I'm having a problem with this snippet, because I can't understand why the second `std::move` is necessary inside the `Mesh::Mesh(std::unique_ptr<VertexArray>&&)`.
From what I understand the assignment operator of `std::unique_ptr` expect rvalue at the right side. Isn't the `vertexArray` (which is type of `std::unique_ptr<VertexArray>&&`) already a rvalue?

Also, the `std::move(vertexArray)` isn't really clear to me, because in this example I guess the `std::move` will return nothing else then `std::unique_ptr<VertexArray>&&`, so isn't it returning exactly the same thing as `vertexArray` already is?

From what I understand, it is, so why do I have to call the `std::move(vertexArray)` where `vertexArray` is already a rvalue, to then convert it to... a rvalue?

Comment: Personally I wouldn't bother with the rvalue reference. Just use e.g. `Mesh(std::unique_ptr<VertexArray> vertexArray)`. Then use a *constructor initializer list* to initialize `vertexArray`. Like `Mesh(std::unique_ptr<VertexArray> vertexArray) : vertexArray{ std::move(vertexArray) } { /* Empty body */ }`

Comment: Maybe it looks like magic because you're not used to tamplates and r-value references (&&). Documentation on both can be found here [introduction to rvalue references](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n2027.html). One of the uses is to allow passing of temporary objects (without copying)

Comment: Unique pointers model a concept known as ownership, and as such you can't copy them. The only way to pass them on is to transfer ownership (move them) and for this you must turn them into rvalue references with std::move. So that move constructors or move assignments will be called that do the transfer of ownership. In case of std::unique_ptr this means the owner of the unique_pointer will determine when it gets deleted.  A much more clear picture then you have with "raw" pointers where you kind of have to do that by documentation (with unique_ptr as you see you get compiler errors)

Comment: This looks very much as if your `vertexArray` member variable should be of type `VertexArray`, not of type `std::unique_ptr<VertexArray>`. Make sure the `VertexArray` type is itself move-constructible.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude That was my initial go :) But then I started wandering about the &&, since I never used it, and couldn't wrap my head around why the second `std::move` is required. I accepted the answer that was put below the question, since it explained my question pretty well.

Comment: *... where vertexArray is already a rvalue...*  Keep this rule-of-thumb in mind:  if it has a name, it is **not** an rvalue.  `vertexArray` is a name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Types and [value categories](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category) are two independent things in C++.

`vertexArray` is an lvalue-expression as it's the name of variable, even its type is rvalue-reference. You have to use `std::move` to convert it to rvalue-expression.

> The following expressions are lvalue expressions:
>
> - the name of a variable, ...

`std::move(vertexArray)` is an xvalue-expression (rvalue-expression), as it's a function call whose return type is rvalue reference.

> The following expressions are xvalue expressions:
>
> - a function call or an overloaded operator expression, whose return type is rvalue reference to object, such as `std::move(x)`;

Comment: I think I'm starting to get it. I had no idea that there is a differentiation between value-expression and value-reference. It makes sense, that my named variable `vertexArray` even though it's an rvalue-reference it's still lvalue expression. And I guess the assignment operator of `unique_ptr` expects the **rvalue-expression** at the right side, it doesn't care about the variable being rvalue-reference? Correct me if I'm wrong, but that makes much more sense now, thank you!

Comment: @y3v4d *And I guess the assignment operator of unique_ptr expects the rvalue-expression at the right side, it doesn't care about the variable being rvalue-reference?* Correct, from perspective of value category. You can just consider about types and value categories separately.